# How to tell Mathematica to get the real-only inverse function?

Tags: equation-solving, functions, numerics, complex, inverse

The problem I have is that Mathematica seems to play better with complex numbers so that the result of `N[InverseFunction[Function[x,x^3]][-1]]` is `0.5 + 0.866025 I` and not `-1` for example. I need to tell Mathematica to evaluate `InverseFunction[Function[x,x^3]]` as a function that simply draws a curve that is symmetric to $y=x$ from $y=x^3$, and the solution to make this happen must also be applicable to any invertible polynomial functions.

Comment: The [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatDoNotHaveUniqueValues.html) elaborates slightly on how the Wolfram Language chooses its branch cuts, but offers little in the way of how to change this behavior. I'd suggest toying around with `Assuming` and `$Assmuptions`, or perhaps using a more robust function than `InverseFunction` such as `Solve` or `Reduce`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Reduce[expr, x, Reals]` will be your friend here, but it can take a bit of work to parse its result.

Here's a solution that should work for any expression, not just polynomials (at least for the small set of examples I tried).

```
RealInverse[a_. x_^q_Integer?Positive + b_., x_] /; FreeQ[{a, b}, x] := 
  Surd[(x-b)/a, q]

RealInverse[expr_, x_] := 
  Module[{y, red},
    red = Reduce[x == (expr /. x -> y), y, Reals];
    ToPW[PWTerm[#, y]& /@ OrList[BooleanConvert[red, "DNF"]], x]
  ]

OrList[HoldPattern[Or][args__]] := {args}
OrList[e_] := {e}

PWTerm[And[cond1___, y_ == root_, cond2___], y_] /; FreeQ[{root, And[cond1, cond2]}, y] := {root, And[cond1, cond2]}
PWTerm[y_ == root_, y_] /; FreeQ[root, y] := {root, True}
PWTerm[___] = $Failed;

ToPW[lis_?MatrixQ, x_] /; Length[First[lis]] == 2 := 
  With[{condlist = Last[Transpose[lis]]},
    Piecewise[lis, Undefined] /; DisjointConditionsQ[condlist, x]
]
ToPW[___] = $Failed;

DisjointConditionsQ[{_}, _] = True;
DisjointConditionsQ[cond_List, x_]:=
  Reduce[And @@ Table[DisjointCondition[cond, i], {i, Length[cond]}], x]

DisjointCondition[cond_, i_] := 
  If[TrueQ[cond[[i]]],
    True,
    Implies[cond[[i]], Not[And @@ Delete[cond, i]]]
]
```

Now some tests:

```
RealInverse[x^3, x]
```

> ```
> Surd[x, 3]
> ```

```
RealInverse[x^7 + x^4 + 3 x - 1, x]
```

> ```
> Root[-1 - x + 3 #1 + #1^4 + #1^7 &, 1]
> ```

```
(* Not invertible over the real line *)
RealInverse[x^3 - 3 x + 1, x]
```

> ```
> $Failed
> ```

```
RealInverse[x^(2/3) + Sqrt[x], x]
```

> ```
> ConditionalExpression[
>   Root[x^6 - 3 x^4 #1 + (3 x^2 - 2 x^3) #1^2 + (-1 - 6 x) #1^3 + #1^4 &, 1], 
>   x >= 0
> ]
> ```

```
RealInverse[Sign[x] (Abs[x]^(2/3) + Sqrt[Abs[x]]), x]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to find and plot the real root of `x^3 == y` is

```
x /. Solve[x^3 == y, x, Reals]
(* {Root[-y + #1^3 &, 1]} *)
Plot[%, {y, -10, 10}, AxesLabel -> {y, x}]
```

[image]

This works for any polynomial `f[x] == y` that has a real root, as requested in the question.  Is this what you had in mind?

**Addendum**

In response to the OP's comment below, a do-it-yourself version of `InverseFunction` that selects real branches, if any, is

```
invfun[g_] := N[x /. First@Solve[g[x] == #, x, Reals]] &
```

Then, the inverse function of

```
f[x_] := x^3
```

is simply

```
invfun[f][y]
```

as can be seen from

```
Plot[invfun[f][y], {y, -10, 10}, AxesLabel -> {y, x}]
```

which returns the plot above.  Note that `y` is a dummy variable, and any symbol can be used in its place; e.g., `invfun[f][w]`.  Note, also, that `invfun` evaluates the `First` real inverse of `f` returned by `Solve`, if there are more than one.  Of course, all this works only for polynomials and (with a bit more work) other functions that can be handled by `Solve`.

Comment: Yours work if plotting the graph is all to achieve, but I explicitly need Mathematica to evaluate the inverse function itself which can be in place of any other function.

Comment: @xiver77 Just turn x /. Solve[x^3 == y, x, Reals] into a function, as thedude did above in his extension to my answer.  I have added a more general response to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
inverseFunc[x_] = x /. Solve[x^3 == y, x, Reals][[1]] /. y -> x;
N@inverseFunc[3]
N@inverseFunc[-1]
(*1.44225*)
(*-1.*)
```